# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table - YII2

Tags: mysql, database, yii2

i'm using Yii2.

I have done a major upgrade of my database during dev phase, and i just put on the prod server the new code. I also dropped the old database, and i installed a fresh dump of the new database.

Despite of that, i have an error while running the application, because yii doesn't find the new table created.

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'yii2basic.INVOICE' doesn't exist

PS: i didn't do any migration/migrate cmd during the dev .. i didn't know that command ..

Thanks for your help

Regards
SB

Comment: yii2basic.INVOICE view is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configuration on mysql server were not the same in prod and dev env.

I set in prod mysql lower case file system=ON, and lower case table=2

Comment: Can you please explain how did you fix it. I am having the same issue.